# cant cast button to start a method

Tags: java, android-studio, onclicklistener

greeting everyone, I have this activity to upload PDF files to firebase storage along with saving data in firebase store but i cannot cast my button upload to the method UploadFile , anyone knows how to make it work?

here is the lines that contain the errors below:-

Button upload ---- 
method UploadFile---

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    Button upload;
    Button select;
    int CODE=215;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        upload=findViewById(R.id.upload);
        select=findViewById(R.id.select);

        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectFile();
            }
        });

        upload.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UploadFile(   );//when i put Uri file it says Cannot resolve symbol 'file' // 
               //and when i remove Uri file from the UploadFile method below then i will get error casted on null //
            }
        } );
    }

    public void selectFile ()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"Select a file"), CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String filePath = data.getDataString();
        Uri SelectedFileLocation=Uri.parse(filePath);
        UploadFile(SelectedFileLocation);

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public  void UploadFile(Uri file)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait.. the file is uploading!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
        StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child(file.getLastPathSegment());

        riversRef.putFile(file)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Upload Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.

Edit 2:
Cleaned up the answer.

You are missing to get the data (persistently) from the result in the onActivityResult method. The uri needs to be stored in a place where you can pass it to the onClickListener of the upload button (for example a field of your UploadActivity object).

You already have `Uri SelectedFileLocation` in your onActivityResult method and do the upload there. Why do you need another button?

Assuming that your manual conversion into the URI provides the same as the default method (`Intent#getData`), just change that variable into field of your UploadActivity.

Don`t forgot to add the not null checks to your UploadFile method or make sure you never call it with invalid values.

Could look like this:

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    Optional<Uri> selectedFile = Optional.empty();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        upload.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (selectedFile.isEmpty() == false) {
                    uploadFile( selectedFile.get() );
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        ...

        if (data != null) {
            selectedFile = Optional.of(data.getData()); 
            uploadFile(selectedFile.get()); // if you still want to do it here as well
        } else {
            selectedFile = Optional.empty();
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Ps.:
Also take a look at the Java Code Conventions.
Methods & variables should start with a lowercase character.

(And its always good practive to leave the @Override on all methods you override)

Comment: Updated the answer, Still check the `Process results` from the provided link. If they recommend to check the requestCode then you should probably do so as well.

Comment: thanks for your replay , i do need that button beacuse the upload button that i have do upload to firebase storage but didnt upload to firebase cloud store ,

Comment: @AmerAnajjem Did this answer your question? If yes, [please accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).